# Global installations - Flask & Python

Tags: python, path, flask, global

How can I tell if flask or python are installed globally? Everytime I attempt to push a flask python app locally I need to copy the flask, jinja2, markupsafe,and werkzeug directories along with file itsdangerous.py

I have had a little experience with paths before, as such I did the `echo $PATH` command and received my path

```
/home/me/rampup/webapp/venv/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Should I append my $PATH with the path locations of python and flask? If so how would I identify the paths of those applications?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to manually copy your dependencies around.  (It's tedious and error prone). Instead, install `pip` (to manage your dependencies) and `virtualenv`[1] (to allow you to work on multiple projects with conflicting dependencies).  Then:

1. Create a virtual environment:  `virtualenv venv`
2. Activate said virtual environment `. venv/bin/activate`
3. Use `pip` to install your dependencies `pip install Flask`
4. There is no step #4

For deployments, simply ask pip to produce a manifest of all the dependencies you have with the command `pip freeze` (you can redirect it to a `requirements.txt` file with the following command `pip freeze > requirements.txt`).  Then you can install the same dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the remote machine.

[1]: If you are on Python 3.4+ you already have both - although you'll use `pyvenv-3.4` instead of `virtualenv`.

Comment: Good answer. Also worth checking out pyenv if you find yourself juggling virtualenvs all the time